# Imported Workflow Error -Path needs to point to valid

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I imported a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow into Visual Studio 2013. Once imported I got this error on all my activities `Path needs to point to valid`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

[image: I imported a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow into Visual Studio 2013. Once imported I got this error on all my activities = Path needs to point to valid. Anyone know how to fix this?]